# Playwright Test execution report

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testng, robotframework, playwright

After the test execution is there any way we can get a report of how many test passed and how many failed in playwright like in robot framework

Answer (score 1):

The new built-in Playwright Test Runner has a number of reporter options. They are documented here:

https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters

There are currently 3 modes to output to the terminal ranging from a very verbose to a very terse output. They are list, line and dot.

There are a further 2 modes intended for output to file. They are json and junit. The former is self-explanatory, the latter produces JUnit-style xml output.

Finally there is the option to generate an HTML report.

The modes can be combined to control the terminal output and file output simultaneously.

Comment: but is there any other third party HTML reports integration like allure or extent reports?

Comment: there is now a 3rd party Allure reporter documented at the above link as well as native HTML reports which can also include a trace viewer if you enabled tracing

Answer (score 0):

You can configure many different reporters, that really depends on what you need, "like in robot framework" is quite broad since you can use different reporters with RF as well.

If you use Playwright with mocha, you can configure even more reporters:

**.mocharc.json**:

```json
{
    "reporter-options": [
        "configFile=reporter-options.json"
    ]
}
```

**reporter-options.json**:

```json
{
    "reporterEnabled": "mocha-simple-html-reporter, spec, mocha-junit-reporter",
    "mochaSimpleHtmlReporterReporterOptions": {
        "output": "./Results/report.html"
    },
    "mochaJunitReporterReporterOptions": {
        "mochaFile": "./Results/report-junit.xml"
    }
}
```

Obviously you have to install dependencies:

**package.json**:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "mocha": "~8.2.1",
        "mocha-junit-reporter": "~2.0.0",
        "mocha-multi-reporters": "~1.5.1",
        "mocha-simple-html-reporter": "~1.1.0",
        "playwright": "~1.10.0"
    }
}
```

After this setup, html and junit reports will be available after test runs. Junit report should be enough so that it could be parsed in a pipeline and displayed on some dashboard.