# playwright Test report in SonarQube

Tags: testing, sonarqube, report, playwright, end-to-end

I would like to display my playwright test in SonarQube. It is possible? if Yes How can we do it?
I will appreciate your support. Any Comment ?

I try to find where playwright sends the report but I couldn't find it.

Comment: I find my answer in this post: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67739060/playwright-test-execution-report)

Comment: Well, you can answer your question and mark as completed :) I almost missed the comment and thought it has no answer.